# Python 3.6 - _tkinter.TclError

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Today I tried to make a text editor using Tkinter's Filedailog, Font and Text functions. But when I tried to run it, It gave me a `tkinter.tclerror`.

I am using **Sublime Text Editor** and **Command Prompt** with a **Virtual Environment**

Here is my Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.title('CodePad Code Editor')
root,geometry("1200x660")


# Create Main Frame which will take text
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# Create Text Box for text input
my_text = Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 16), selectbakground="yellow", selectforeground="black", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)
my_text.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

And this was the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
 line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
 line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "e:\Python-Projects\text_editor\TextEditor.py", line 5, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__
init__.py", line 2017, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError
```

Anybody please tell me what can I do to clear the error

Thanks

Steve

Comment: The code as posted will not give that error.

Comment: `root,geometry("1200x660")` - is this a typo or actual code?

Comment: @BryanOakley I guess then I have to reinstall My Python

Comment: `yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set` looks dubious. Where is text_scroll?

Comment: I don't know if you have to reinstall or not. First you need to give us a [mcve] that reproduces the error you say you're getting. The code you gave us has errors that prevent it from running.

Comment: Typos errors: `root,geometry` should be `root.geometry` and `selectbakground` should be `selectbackground`